# In google sheets if I have two columns next to each other, how can I combine them automatically into a single column? NOT concatenation?

Tags: google-sheets

So in other words if column one is

```
1
2
3
```

and column two

```
4
5
6
```

There should be just one column

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that the very definition of concatenation? Maybe you need to change your question title.

Comment: Nope- concatenation combines them all into a single cell- here the question was to rearrange them into seperate cells in a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine ranges by putting them in brackets `{}`, with the ranges separated by a semicolon `;`.

In your case you would have `={A1:A3;B1:B3}` in the cell you wish to put your new list in (`A1:A3` being column one and `B1:B3` being column two). Change the ranges as you need, accordingly.